# Pthreads in XAMPP in linux

Tags: ubuntu, xampp, pthreads

As for pthreads library,PHP must be compile with ZTS.Is this possible to install Pthreads in XAMPP in linux.Because for windows XAMPP,it may be not any issue.

Can you please correct my scenario for this installations or links with XAMPP?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

PHP comes with PECL (PHP Extension Community Library) command support by default, which saves us the hassle of having to compile the extension manually. We can instead just run the installation command below.

```
$ pecl install pthreads

$ echo "extension=pthreads.so" >> /etc/php.ini
```

With the extension now successfully installed, we must now include the extension to be loaded in the 'php.ini' configuration file. We can test that the extension has been successfully loaded with the PHP interpretor by running and inspecting the output from the following command.

```
$ php -m | grep pthreads
```

More detail you will get from below link

[Compiling PHP 5.5 with ZTS and pthreads Support](http://eddmann.com/posts/compiling-php-5-5-with-zts-and-pthreads-support/)

Answer (score 0):

in recent Linux OS systems pthread is already available.

for usage check [yolinux.com](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialPosixThreads.html)