# pthreads installation ubuntu

Tags: php, multithreading, ubuntu, xampp

I have this problem when I try to run threads class
Class 'Thread' not found

some things my be you found it useful 
i use lampp  and I modified  the php.ini and i add this to extensions:
extension=php_pthreads.dll

my php v is PHP 7.0.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 (cli) ( NTS )

and I try this for installation 
http://php.net/manual/en/pthreads.installation.php

and [Pthreads in XAMPP in linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25841369/pthreads-in-xampp-in-linux)

but not thing work to me

Comment: Are you sure you correctly followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26295091) in the question you linked correctly?  Note how it suggests to add `extension=pthreads.so` to your `php.ini`, rather than `extension=php_pthreads.dll`.

Comment: NTS = Not Thread Safe. You need to have a ZTS (Zend Thread Safe) version of PHP installed.

Comment: @CandyGumdrop  it doesn't   work  to add extension=pthreads.so